# GitHub Merge Queue Workflow Triggering Twice

Tags: github-actions

I'm currently trying to experiment with GitHub's merge queue, and have configured a new workflow using the [merge_group event](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#merge_group). Unfortunately, the workflow is triggering twice when the PR is added to the merge queue, and I'm unable to figure out why.

[image: Merge Queue Flow Triggered Twice]

The configuration I am trying is:

```
name: PR Merge Queue
on:
  merge_group:
    types: [ checks_requested ]
    branches: [ test_target ]
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    name: PR Merge Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    ...
```

Is there something I've missed?

UPDATE:
The two workflows have different SHA's. The first is target HEAD + the PR. The second is that plus the PR again. `git log --oneline <SHA_from_second_workflow>` shows:

```
5ddf4a00ac5 (origin/gh-readonly-queue/test_target/pr-4326-ba2fe09b50638c37910cd6e538e6d35fe7207e41) Remove branches option (#4326)
ba2fe09b506 (HEAD -> test_target, origin/test_target) Remove branches option (#4326)
adcdbbca670 previous test_target HEAD (#4325)
```

Maybe this is some bug with merge queue?

UPDATE 2:
I created a GitHub support ticket. Other similar issues are being reported and they are investigating.

Comment: Maybe you're commiting it twice? What's in the history?

Comment: It's a single PR with a single commit. However, the two workflows have different SHA's. The first is target HEAD + the PR. The second is target HEAD + the PR + the PR again (but with no changes). So maybe a merge queue bug?

Comment: I think we have found the same thing, which GitHub have told us is a bug

Comment: A potential workaround... Under your repo, try navigating to settings -> branches, and enable "Require status checks to pass before merging". This appeared to prevent duplicate workflows being triggered.